# Replace escaped characters with their actual characters in C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, escaping

I have a string of HTML content that looks like:

```
<article aria-labelledby=\"aritcle-title-1\" class=\"col-md-12\">\n</article>
```

I want to replace the escaped characters with their actual characters:

Replace: \n With: String.Empty

Replace: \" With: "

I was using:

```
model.ContentHTML.Replace("\n", "");
```

But I can't figure out how to replace the escaped quote with an actual quote. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
model.ContentHTML.Replace("\\\"", "\"");
```

The first two backslashes resolve to a single backslash, and the `\"` resolves to a `"`

You can also use [Regex.Unescape()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape(v=vs.110).aspx), if you're so inclined.